# Retain values with transpose

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like below table.

```
KEY   Week  DEMAND
Item_1  1   6.3
Item_1  2   6.3
Item_1  3   6.3
Item_1  4   6.3
Item_1  5   7.7
```

What i want is to transpose data (But with cumulative the demand) using pandas data frame.
result data i have pasted below to make it easy to understand.

the result should look like below table.

```
KEY   Week DEMAND   FCST1   FCST2   FCST3   FCST4   FCST5   
Item_1  1   6.3      6.3    6.3     6.3      6.3    6.3 
Item_1  2   6.3     12.5    6.3     6.3      6.3    6.3 
Item_1  3   6.3     18.8   12.5     6.3      6.3    6.3
Item_1  4   6.3     25.0   18.8    12.5      6.3    6.3
Item_1  5   6.7     31.8   25.5    19.3     13.0    6.7
```

**in the result for 1st week every fcst column is same.**

**for the 2nd week FCST1 (lag of fcst1 + demand of week2) is the cumulative and other FCST is having the value of week2's demand.**

**for the 3rd week fcst1 (lag of fcst1 + demand of week3), fcst2 (lag of fcst2 + demand of week3) is cumulative and other fcst is having same value as week3's demand.**

like this i have bunch of item, I want to do the same operation for every item.

I have done same in SAS by using array with do loop and retaining the values.

Can anyone help me out to crack this in python.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is essentially

1. self-merge on `KEY`
2. get the week lags by comparing two weeks
3. get the demand lags by cumsum
4. pivot the data and fill

```
    (df.merge(df, on='KEY', suffixes=('_x',''))
       .query('Week_x<=Week')
       .assign(val=lambda x: x.groupby(['KEY','Week_x'])['DEMAND_x'].cumsum())
       .pivot_table(index=['KEY','Week', 'DEMAND'], columns='Week_x', values='val')
       .ffill(axis=1) 
       .add_prefix('FCST')
       .reset_index()
    )
```

Output:

```
Week_x     KEY  Week  DEMAND  FCST1  FCST2  FCST3  FCST4  FCST5
0       Item_1     1     6.3    6.3    6.3    6.3    6.3    6.3
1       Item_1     2     6.3   12.6    6.3    6.3    6.3    6.3
2       Item_1     3     6.3   18.9   12.6    6.3    6.3    6.3
3       Item_1     4     6.3   25.2   18.9   12.6    6.3    6.3
4       Item_1     5     7.7   31.5   25.2   18.9   12.6    7.7
```

Comment: Yes, Worked perfectly the way i wanted.
Kudos.......